# Merge text nodes to one text node and wrap inside a p-tag. Javascript/ JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html document that consists of several text nodes, usually wrapped in p-tags, but some are not. Like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  "Some text" "Some text" "Some text"
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  "Some text" "Some text" "Some text"
</div>
```

I found a way to wrap all text nodes inside p-tags with Jquery, but this is not what I want to achieve.

```
 function getTextNodesIn(node, includeWhitespaceNodes) {
    var textNodes = [], whitespace = /^\s*$/;

    function getTextNodes(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            if (includeWhitespaceNodes || !whitespace.test(node.nodeValue)) {
                textNodes.push(node);
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                getTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    getTextNodes(node);
    return textNodes;
}

var textnodes = getTextNodesIn($("#container")[0]);
for(var i=0; i < textnodes.length; i++) {
    if(($(textnodes[i]).parent().is("#container"))) {
        $(textnodes[i]).wrap("<p>");
    }
}
```

I want all text nodes between p-tags that does not have a p-tag wrapped around them to get merged to one text node, and then wrap a p-tag around that text node. Like this:

```
<div>
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  <p>"Some text Some text Some text"</p>
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  <p>"Some text Some text Some text"</p>
</div>
```

Is this possible? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to empty the container and add all child wrapped with a `<p>`.
So you don't care if original text have a "p" or not, you take the text and wrap with a "p".
The code is more simple and readable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var original = $("#container").text().split("\n");
  $("#container").empty();
  $(original).each(function(a,b){
    $("#container").append("<p>" + b + "</p>");
  });
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/wogoyuvaci) you have a fiddle with working example.

Answer (score 0):

This keeps the HTML inside the paragraphs and wraps the 'intervals' between paragraphs in a paragraph, it saves the base nodes and the intervals to a list and then rebuilds it in order.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container").childNodes;
var ps = [];
var ps_interval = [];
for(var i=0; i < container.length; i++){
  if(container[i].nodeType == 3){ //if its a textnode
    var str = container[i].textContent.trim();
    if(str !== ""){
      ps_interval.push(str);
    }
  }else{
    if(container[i].nodeName != 'P'){ //if it's not a paragraph
      ps_interval.push(container[i]);  
    }else{
      if(ps_interval.length !== 0){
        ps.push(ps_interval);
        ps_interval = [];
      }
      ps.push(container[i]);
    }
  }
}
if(ps_interval.length !== 0){
  ps.push(ps_interval);
}

function addToP(interval){
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  for(var j=0; j< interval.length; j++){
    if("string" == typeof interval[j]){
      p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(interval[j]));
    }else{
      p.appendChild(interval[j]);
    }
  }
  return p;
}

$('#container').empty();
for(var k=0; k < ps.length; k++){
  if( Object.prototype.toString.call( ps[k] ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    $('#container').append(addToP(ps[k]));
  }else{
    $('#container').append(ps[k]);
  }
}
```

Got it working [here](http://jsbin.com/qibovusoti/edit?html,js,output).